# Internal Server 500 error classic asp on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5

I recently moved a classic asp site on to a Windows 2008 server running IIS 7.5.

The home page is a frames page with two frames on it - the bottom frame contains two iframes. A javascript timer runs in the header frame and forces the pages in the two iframes to reload every 10 minutes. All other things being equal, this works perfectly - and sessions never time out. On the screen I display 'last update at 10.35' - so users can see when the last update was. Every page within the main frames page - and the iframes - has, at the top ..

```
IF IsEmpty(Session("CoID")) THEN
Response.Write ... some javascript to replace the main page with the log in page
END IF
```

As I say - this works perfectly most of the time.

Using the site as a user - if my box goes to sleep and the refreshes don't work because the internet connection is not available - when I wake the box up the page might be sitting there with last update at 10.50 (for example, this might be two hours ago). Immediately the machine wakes up the refresh tries to happen - now you'd think the session would be lost and the code that detects the empty session would kick in and replace the page with the log in page. But, this doesn't happen. Instead I get two 500 internal server error messages where the two pages in the iframes should be.

What I don't understand is - if I right click the header and select 'Refresh' - it does what it should - detects the session is empty and replaces the main page with the log in page. Why are the two pages in iframes not doing the same thing? The detect empty session code is identical on all the pages but, for some reason, when the refresh tries to reload the pages in the two iframes - a 500 internal server error is generated.

Comment: What is causing the 500 errors? Have you enabled detailed errors in IIS to see what line it's falling over on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest assigning `Session("CoID")` to a variable and then testing it, i.e.

```
Dim sess
sess = Session("CoID")

If sess = "" Then 
    ' code you want to execute '
End If
```

Since `IsEmpty` will sometimes unexpectedly validate as `true` for strings that have had a blank line assigned to them, I think checking if the variable is equal to `""` is safer.